# Configuring squid/Samba for NTLM v1 only

Tags: ntlm, squid

First a bit of background here. This question is for a server not exposed to the wilds of the internet, a private network with no outside networking.  Its for QA testing of a product and needs to be tested, so security is a joke.  On with the question:

*Is it possible to configure Squid3/Samba to only accept NTLMv1 authentication?*

I've already built a Squid3/Samba for NTLMv2. But I'm lost on how to configure Squid3/Samba to accept only NTLMv1.

Current Squid conf:

```
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --diagnostics --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp

auth_param ntlm children 25
auth_param ntlm keep_alive on
acl ntlm proxy_auth REQUIRED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while for this.  So I'll post my answer.  I had to do a strange filter to the system to deny NTLMv2 requests using a Bluecoat/Packeteer hardware.  Not much of an answer, but it will close this.